# WelcomeController can't find path to index.html

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working on some WebApplication with SpringBoot MVC pattern. I have four maven projects (DAO project, REST project(there is SpringBoot class for starting application), SERVICE project and CLIENT project). This projects are connected through dependencies.

My problem is with CLIENT project. There I have WelcomeController which is look like this :

```
package com.itengine.scoretracker.client.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(){
        return "static/html/index.html";
    }
}
```

And my html's are on this path:

[image]

When I relocate my static folder from CLIENT project in REST project on same location, my WelcomeController see index.html and everything works fine.

So please, can somebody help me with this issue, i really need this html's in CLIENT project. I dont have experience with configuration xml's because i learned on course SpringBoot without those xml's.

My web.xml's are empty, they have only this:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application    2.3//EN" "java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd"; > <web-app> <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name> </web-app>
```

My main class is like this:

```
package com.itengine.scoretracker.rest.init;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@ComponentScan("com.itengine")
@EntityScan("com.itengine")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.itengine.scoretracker.dao.repository")
@SpringBootApplication
public class ScoreTrackerApplication
    extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder builder){

        return builder.sources(ScoreTrackerApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ScoreTrackerApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this class ScoreTrackerApplication in your client project?

Comment: No she is in Rest project

Comment: so the client is not a spring boot project till now . Just create a class in client and annotate it with @SpringBootApplication

Comment: I do that, and that solved my problem. Tnx @BalajiKrishnan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `static` folder to `src/main/resources` so that it ends up deployed on the classpath. The mapping for `/` can then be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Now, like u say @Reimeus, I have this situation:

[image]

And that won't working. And what with removing / mapping??

Comment: probably view resolver issue.. like @Reimeus said, the static folder under src/main/resources should work in spring boot

Comment: In my web.xml i have only this: 

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>

Comment: where is the config class annotated with @SpringBootApplication

Answer (score 0):

If your `index.html` is plain html, your controller is unnecessary.

Just put the `index.html` in `src/main/resources/static`.

That's all you need. Spring boot takes care of the rest.

You also don't need a web.xml.